# Given a list of files, some duplicates, some not, show checksum of only the duplicates

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python

There must be an "easy" way to do this, but I can't figure out what it is.

Assume you have a plain text "file.txt" which has lines in this format (md5 sums followed by filenames):

```
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 foo.txt
365a6d8b18cab348d92db610dfc46264 bar.txt
ae42d992bf622bdc425d37b04ec9c2d5 mini.txt
b8e9ff5502d5dbe38b3fd5e3363caacf tyrion.txt
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 imac.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 mba.txt
310ee92ebc69ed79c1837fc53983b7f8 mini luoma.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 tyrion final.txt
```

I would like to sort `file.txt` and have the output:

1. Only show me lines if the md5 sum indicates the files are duplicates
2. Put a blank line between each "group" of duplicates.

so it would look like this:

```
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 mba.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 tyrion final.txt

5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 foo.txt
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 imac.txt
```

(In the real case, it could be 2 duplicates or 10, or more.)

I'm guessing there might be a `ruby` or `python` guru out there who can figure this one out, but I'm open to pretty much any practical solution out there.

Comment: You do realize this is not enough to rule out hash collisions. Better to add another indicator like file size, when creating your list. Sure, you might still get collisions but the probability is much lower.

Comment: The better solution would be to use a deduplicating filesystem like zfs, and have it maintain single copy of files under the hood (converting duplicates to hardlinks)

Comment: let's assume that `zfs` isn't a practical solution

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sort file.txt \
| grep -f <(cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -d) \
| awk 'last && last != $1 { printf "\n" }; { last=$1 ; print}'

542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 mba.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 tyrion final.txt

5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 foo.txt
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 imac.txt
```

(Thanks to "cas" for the awk suggestion.)

(And thanks to "steeldriver" for noticing a bug.)

Comment: +1.  and just pipe the output to `awk 'last && last != $1 { printf "\n" }; { last=$1 ; print}'`.    This prints a blank line whenever variable last is not empty and is different to the current $1.  feel free to add this to your answer :)

Comment: @cas, thanks.  I'd just come up with something similar, but not quite as nice:  ``awk 'BEGIN { x="" }; { if (x != $1)  print(""); print; x=$1 }'``.  It's amazing how much one forgets in only a few years, and even more amazing how quickly one relearns it.

Comment: an alternative could be `grep -f <(cat file | sort | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -d) file`

Comment: Doesn't the grouping here rely on the order in which entries happen to get grepped from the original file? it could be fixed by sorting that as well e.g. replacing `file.txt` by `<(sort file.txt)` in shells that support process substitution.

Comment: @steeldriver.  Yes, that was indeed a bug.

Answer (score 3):

With `sort` and `uniq`

```
sort file.txt | uniq -w 32 --all-repeated=separate
```

```
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 mba.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 tyrion final.txt

5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 foo.txt
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 imac.txt
```

- `-w 32` limits `uniq` comparison to the MD5 hash (so it considers equals lines with same MD5)
- `--all-repeated=separate` tells it to show duplicates, while separating groups with a blank line

Comment: is that GNU `uniq`, to support the `--all-repeated` option?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes

Comment: There wasn't a Linux tag, so it's worth pointing out the use of tools that might only be available on certain systems; thanks!

Comment: @jeffschaller You mean,  like gawk and perl in other answers?

Comment: Not really; `gawk` is `GNU awk`, and perl's invocation doesn't differ across implementations. Since `--all-repeated` is only available in certain `uniq` implementations, it can avoid confusion by simply mentioning that implementation. If the question was tagged Linux, you could (more) safely assume that the `uniq` tool there was GNU's.

Comment: I'm actually on macOS/Darwin, so it's good to know. I can use `guniq` from "GNU coreutils" available via Brew.sh.

Answer (score 2):

With a perl Hash of Arrays:

```
$ perl -alne '
    push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $_ 
    }{ 
    for $k (sort keys %h) {
      @a = @{ $h{$k} }; 
      print join "\n", @a, "" if $#a  > 0
    }
' file.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 mba.txt
542ed609dfc4d0cae44c4b7be6d66382 tyrion final.txt

5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 foo.txt
5ee434a2ebcf4c3c98ee07e9c1efddc0 imac.txt
```

Note that this prints a trailing blank line after the last record. The `sort` is optional.

---

Similar thing in GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  {a[$1][NR] = $0} 
  END {
    for(k in a){
      if(length(a[k]) > 1) {
        for(v in a[k]) print a[k][v];
        print "";
      }
    }
  }   
' file.txt
```